# Find the general solution differential equation $y''+3y'-10y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find the general solution differential equation $$y''+3y'-10y=0$$ using constants of integration $ \ C_1, C_2, C_3, ......... \ $ and express the solution **using multiplication sign** as

[image]

**Answer:**

As usual  , the general solution is given by

$ y=C_1 e^{2x}+C_2 e^{-5x} \ $

But how to express the solution using multiplication sign ?

**I think** , we have to express the solution as $ y=[f(x)] \times [g(x)] \ $.

But I am unable to express it.

Is there any way to derive the solution in the above form?

**Help me out.**

Comment: Maybe they wanted something like $C_1\times e^{2x}+C_2\times e^{-5x}$? Or $e^{2x}\times(C_1 + C^2 e^{-7x})$? Other than that, I don't see how the requirement can be fullfilled.

Comment: your solution is right $$y=y_h+y_p$$ the general solution of the homogeneous equation and a particular solution of the nonhomogeneous one

Comment: please look at the question again , it has been asked into a ' box'

Comment: My only suggestion would be the second of @TZakrevskiy's comments. But surely this came up in a class and you were told what was expected in your homework.